# Change the functionality of a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Currently I have a display where I have a button START, on click of this button the timer starts and it gets replaced by 2 buttons. these 2 buttons are submit and walkaway. on the submit of each of these buttons a script is run. on the click of submit button, test.php is initiated.

Everything is working fine, but there are few changes that i am not able to make

First

> I wish to combine the start and submit button, i.e
>
> a) on the click of start button, timer should start,
>
> b) the 2 new buttons should appear and
>
> c) the script test.php should run.
>
> *it would be nice if i could just change the text of start button to
>   submit and keep the button same and run the above 3 functionalities on
>   click of start button, however different aspects are also welcomed*

Second

> when the time of the timer reaches 0:00 it should get reset to its initial stage and the buttons should also get changed to their original state i.e
>
> a) the 2 buttons should disappear and get replaced by start button
>
> b) clock should show its initial value i.e 2:00

Part of js code. entire code [@fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/jrs35tvk/)

```
/*******Code for the three buttons*********/
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("#startClock").click(function (){
                $("#startClock").fadeOut(function(){
$("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
$("#submitamt").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut(function(){
        $("#startClock").fadeIn();
        });
    })
});
});

/*******Code for running test.php script*********/
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitamt').click(function(){
    var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
    var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
             url:'test.php',
            data:{txt:txtbox,hidden:hiddenTxt},
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
                console.log(returndata)
            }
        });
})
})

/*******Code for starting the clock*********/
$('#startClock').click(function () {
    var counter = 120;
    setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = '<span class="first_digit">' + parseInt(counter / 60) + '</span><span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">' + parseInt((counter % 60) / 10) + '</span> <span class="fourth_digit">' + (counter % 60) % 10;
        }
        if (counter === 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: You say 2 buttons on click of start has to be displayed and you want to replace start button text with submit text right? and walkaway button remains as it is??

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao the requirement is that the click of the start button, displays 2 other button. the replacement of the text is my personal idea that it maybe done like this. the working remains as is in the fiddle. and yes the walkaway button simply appears and disappears with the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example (using different buttons rather than changing button's text):

```js
var startClock;
var submitamt;
var walkaway;
var digits;

$(function() {
  startClock = $('#startClock').on('click', onStart);
  submitamt = $('#submitamt').on('click', onSubmit);
  walkaway = $('#walkaway').on('click', onWalkAway);
  digits = $('#count span');
  beforeStart();
});

var onStart = function(e) {
  startClock.fadeOut(function() {
    startTimer();
    submitamt.fadeIn(function() {
      submitamt.trigger('click'); // fire click event on submit
    });
    walkaway.fadeIn();
  });
};

var onSubmit = function(e) {
  var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
  var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      txt: txtbox,
      hidden: hiddenTxt
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(returndata) {
      $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
      console.log(returndata);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
    }
  });
};

var onWalkAway = function(e) {
  console.log('onWalkAway ...');
};

var counter;
var timer;
var startTimer = function() {
  counter = 120;
  timer = null;
  timer = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
};

var beforeStart = function() {
  digits.eq(0).text('2');
  digits.eq(2).text('0');
  digits.eq(3).text('0');
};

var ticker = function() {
  counter--;
  var t = (counter / 60) | 0; // it is round off
  digits.eq(0).text(t);
  t = ((counter % 60) / 10) | 0;
  digits.eq(2).text(t);
  t = (counter % 60) % 10;
  digits.eq(3).text(t);
  if (!counter) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    alert('Time out !');
    resetView();
  }
};

var resetView = function() {
  walkaway.fadeOut();
  submitamt.fadeOut(function() {
    beforeStart();
    startClock.fadeIn();
  });
};
```

```css
.first_digit
 {
 width:60px; 
 font-size:40px; 
 padding:4px;
 color: #CCC; 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000; 
 text-align: center; 
 background-color: #333;
 border-radius: 6px; 
 }
 
.second_digit
 {
  color: #333; 
  font-size:40px; 
 }

.third_digit
 {
 width:60px; 
 font-size:40px; 
 padding:4px;
 color: #CCC; 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000; 
 text-align: center; 
 background-color: #333;
 border-radius: 6px; 
 }
 
.fourth_digit
 {
 width:60px; 
 font-size:40px; 
 padding:4px;
 color: #CCC; 
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000; 
 text-align: center; 
 background-color: #333;
 border-radius: 6px; 
 }
 
.countdown
{
text-align:center; 
margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countdown">
 <span id="count">
  <span class="first_digit">2</span>
  <span class="second_digit">:</span>
  <span class="third_digit">0</span>
  <span class="fourth_digit">0</span>
 </span> 
</div>
<button class="rightbtn" type="button" id="startClock">Start</button>
<button class="rightbtn" type="button" id="submitamt" style="display:none; ">Submit</button>
<button class="botleftbtn" type="button" id="walkaway" style="display:none">Walk Away</button>
```

Comment: things seems to be fine, but i also wish to run a script test.php on the click of start button

Comment: the php script is running but the clock is not working, it gives an alert message after 2 minutes, but doesn't show the time

Comment: yes it is working here, it is working in my page also but the time remains 2:00 and after 2 min the popup appears

Comment: @user3732711, kindly find my updated script, copy all

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Please refer HTML in **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/jrs35tvk/2/)**. Have made some changes

```
$('.rightbtn').on('click', function(){
    var btn=$(this);
    if(btn.data('type')==='start')
    {
        btn.text('Submit').data('type','submit');
        $("#walkaway").fadeIn();
        count2=setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = '<span class="first_digit">' + parseInt(counter / 60) + '</span><span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">' + parseInt((counter % 60) / 10) + '</span> <span class="fourth_digit">' + (counter % 60) % 10;
        }
        if (counter === 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(counter);
            btn.text('Start').data('type','start');
            $("#walkaway").fadeOut();
        }
        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        clearTimeout(count);
        counter=0;
        clearInterval(counter);
        clearInterval(count2);
        btn.text('Start').data('type','start');
        $("#walkaway").fadeOut();
        span = document.getElementById("count");
        span.innerHTML = '<span class="first_digit">2</span><span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">0</span> <span class="fourth_digit">0';
        var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
        var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
       $.ajax({
            type:'post',
             url:'test.php',
            data:{txt:txtbox,hidden:hiddenTxt},
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $('#proddisplay').html(returndata);
                console.log(returndata)
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: although the timer works in fiddle with your code, but it is not working in my script, the timer code is placed at the end of the script and the rest of the code is at the top of the page i.e head portion, when i am using ur code it either performs no action or the button disappears randomly

Comment: @user3732711.. Did you try to create template as shown in DEMO.. I've added a class and removed all other unnecessary things from `js` and warpped all the code in a single click

Comment: You might need to post the whole set of `html` then to see where you facing issue!!

Answer (score 0):

This will merge you start and submit button ....

```
$('#startClock').click(function () {
var counter = 120;
setInterval(function () {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count");
        span.innerHTML = '<span class="first_digit">' + parseInt(counter / 60) + '</span><span class="second_digit">:</span><span class="third_digit">' + parseInt((counter % 60) / 10) + '</span> <span class="fourth_digit">' + (counter % 60) % 10;
    }
    if (counter === 0) {
        alert('sorry, out of time');
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}, 1000);

$('#submitamt').click();
```

});

this is like appending the submit function at the end of start function.
I hope this will help